# How to confirm that database update successful

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've learned that android database writing is a slow process which takes some time to process. How can I get notification that the database writing/update is successful before doing any other job on system?

For example I'm writing a SMS application which checks database for pending messages. When it finds pending messages then it sends the SMS & update the message status to success.

I'm running loop to find pending SMS. As updating database takes some time so in this time the loop is running several times & multiple SMS are sent. If I could wait until successful database update then this problem would be solved.

Thanks everyone

Comment: do you mean update to a column/table?

Comment: Updates are processed in the order they're received. What exactly do you fear happening if for some reason an update hasn't completed by the time it has been received? The second one will not skip over the first.

Comment: @thinksteep
Yes I mean update a column

Comment: @Aidanc
I'm editing the question to make it clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your update in a transaction and you'll be guaranteed that your data won't be used in mid-update.